# Java - Is there a way to query an Apache Spark schema without iterating?

Tags: java, apache-spark, struct, schema

I'm trying to find out if there's a way to directly query a struct from a Spark schema derived from a dataset of rows. Is there some sort of Java equivalent to the Scala provided dataframe.schema("nameOfStruct")?

I've tried finding such a prebuilt function, but the only thing I could find was a way to iterate through a list of Structs or make an iterator. This seems really redundant when Scala provides a much easier way of doing things, especially if I don't want to check through a loop or find the exact index of my desired Struct.

```java
//adding the metadata to a column
final Metadata metadata = new MetadataBuilder().putLong("metadataExample", 1).build();
final Dataset<Row> dfWithColumnMetadata = df1.withColumn("column_example", df.col("column_example"), metadata);

/*now I want to find the exact Struct and its metadata without having to loop through 
an array or create an iterator. However, the array version is the easiest way I could find. 
The con here is that I need to know the exact index of the column.*/
System.out.println(dfWithColumnMetadata.schema().fields()[0].metadata().toString());
```

Is there a way that I could get something like Scala's df.schema("column_example").metadata() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
dfWithColumnMetadata.schema().apply("column_example").metadata()
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Seems like you might have given an alternate Scala answer, although I'm not sure enough to confirm that. Java doesn't have a metadata() function off of a column (which is what apply("column") returns). I'm just trying to find a way to retrieve the Metadata object from the column as easily as possible.

Comment: ive edited my answer, sorry i made a mistake and forgot to put in the schema() call between the daftaframe and the apply() function. Hope this helps

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for your help!